# How to get Location 3D cursor by Script

Tags: python, scripting, blender-internal-render-engine

In View from Top screen, I want get location 3Dcursor by script, when i click change 3dcursor point.
Can you help me.

thank you so much!

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get the cursor location using `bpy.context.scene.cursor_location`

to change the cursor location you just set its values as shown here `bpy.context.scene.cursor_location = (0,0,0)`

In blender 2.80+, the syntax is :

`bpy.context.scene.cursor.location = (0,0,0)`

Comment: @LdHòa I've updated my answer. If you want to set the `cursor_location` then you set it using `bpy.context.scene.cursor_location = (0,0,0)`

Comment: I saw your answer. I want to find event when mouser click change position in View from Top screen -> print new cursor_location.

Comment: @LdHòa I'm not sure what you mean, this `bpy.context.scene.cursor_location` will give you the current location of the cursor shown in the 3D Cursor location panel

Comment: There are very few events you can get with python api ( https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_61_release/bpy.app.handlers.html also good read: https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_71_release/info_quickstart.html#preface ), you'd have to poll cursor position yourself to know when position changed.

Comment: fyi In Blender 2.8 it is:
`bpy.context.scene.cursor`

[Docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.80/bpy.types.Scene.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use `bpy.context.scene.cursor.location` for Blender 3+